# _super and _super_ keywords in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I'm fairly new to JS and in the course of reading about prototypes and such I've run across various examples that use keywords such as `_super` or `_super_`

Are those native javascript constructs, as with the prototype, or some add-ons that third party libraries implement to help with inheritance?

Comment: Those are just regular properties.

Comment: Just FYI, I would avoid messing with them if you're thinking about doing that. JS doesn't have private variables, so the `_name` convention is commonly taken to mean "this is used behind the scenes by some other code in the same framework, you're not meant to access it." That doesn't mean you shouldn't try to understand it, though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These words are just third party add-ons. There is no `_super` or `_super_` reserved word in JavaScript.

***Reference:*** https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Lexical_grammar#Keywords